# About the order and direction of the list in CSS Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

If you list the list with flex, it looks something like this.

```
12
34
56
```

How can I arrange this in flex like this?
Is there a way to do it?

```
14
25
36
```

By the way, in case of increasing to seven

```
15
26
37
4
```

It is like feeling.

```css
.list_number {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.list_number > li {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<ul class="list_number">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think columns is more suitable in this case : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kjusobmd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this but as @TemaniAfif mentioned in the comments, the easiest method to do this would be to use columns like this:

```
ul{
    columns: 2;
 }
```

Just add that to your css and you can achieve the same thing with just one line of code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is probably the cleanest and most straightforward CSS-only approach of doing this. +1

Comment: Oh I did not see his comment , But anyways , Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: column` and `max-height` should do the trick.

Comment: Please post a complete answer. Show us how your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a JavaScript approach, you can just retrieve the height of an `<li>` element (assuming that all the `<li>` elements are the same height), multiply it into half the number of `<li>'s` inside your `<ul>` element and set the height of the ul to that value. (*If the number of `<li>'s` is an **odd number**, just add the height of **one more `<li>`** to the value.*)

Also, make sure the parent flex container `.list_number` has the properties `flex-direction: column;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` so that elements will automatically go the next column when previous elements have filled the height.

---

Check and run the **Code Snippet** below for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
/* JavaScript */
const div = document.querySelector(".list_number");
const lists = document.querySelectorAll(".list_number li");
const height = window.getComputedStyle(lists[0]).height;

div.style.height = (lists.length % 2 == 0) ? (parseInt(height) * lists.length / 2) + "px" : (parseInt(height) * lists.length / 2) + parseInt(height) + "px";
```

```css
/* CSS */

html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}

.list_number{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<ul class="list_number">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```